# Как правильно промисифицировать функцию? Правильно ли я решил задачу?

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть функция:

```
let bb = (callback, x, y) => setTimeout(() => callback(null, x + y), 200)
```

Как написать функцию обертку promisify(f), принимающую исходную функцию и возвращающую promise

Пример:

```
const promisedbb = promisify(bb);


promisedbb(1, 2).then(res => console.log(res)); // => ’3’
```

У меня получилось так:

```js
function promisify (f) {
  return function (...args) { // возвращает функцию-обёртку
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      f((err, script) => {
        if (err) reject(err)
        else resolve(script)
      }, ...args)
    })
  }
};
```

правильно ли я решил задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно!

Замените только `script` на `result`, а то глаза слезятся :)

Хозяйке на заметку, в ноде уже есть такая утилита https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original, только она принимает функцию, у которой `callback` - это последний аргумент, а не первый.

Answer (score 1):

Все ок, только немножко многословно.
Как вариант:

```js
const promisify = func => (...args) => new Promise((yay, nay) => 
  func((err, rslt) => err ? nay(err) : yay(rslt), ...args)
);

let bb = (callback, x, y) => setTimeout(() => callback(null, x + y), 200); 
const bbPromised = promisify(bb);
bbPromised(1, 2).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Только это неприменимо в среде угрюмых разработчиков. Теоретически - могут побить))